# Average slope of a curve (right side of the equation) intuition

Tags: average, slope

Okay, I can somehow understand why average slope of a curve is defined in such a fashion: 
Let $f$ be a continuous function on an interval $[a,b]$. Then, we define its average over $[a,b]$ to be the number
$$
f_{\operatorname{avg}} := {1 \over b-a} \int_a^b f(t) dt
$$
Let $y = F(x)$ be a curve. Fix the starting point $x_0$ and the ending point $x_1=x_0+\Delta x$. Then, the slope at a point $z$ is the derivative $F'(z)$. Thus, the "average slope'' should mean
\begin{equation*}
(F')_{\operatorname{avg}} = {1 \over x_1 - x_0}\int_{x_0}^{x_1} F'(t) dt = {F(x_1) - F(x_0) \over x_1-x_0}.
\end{equation*}

To summarize: "Avg. slope = Sum all slopes of all tangent lines over an interval $[a,b]$ and divide it by the number of slopes over that same interval."
But right side of the equation somehow bothers me. I don't get intuitevely how average slope (sum of all slopes/number of slopes) equals slope of a function $F(x)$ between two endpoints $x_0$ and $x_1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right side is the slope of the line drawn between $(x_0,F(x_0))$ and $(x_1,F(x_1))$.  I would see that as the definition of average slope.  Averaging an infinite number of local slopes is more problematic.  The right side only depends on two values of the function.

Comment: Part 1: What is your interpretation of that right side that is straight-forward to be "definition of average slope"? For me it's easier to first start with conclusion that average slope = sum of all slopes/ number of slopes (like average value of something).

Comment: Part 2: 
Since you are dealing with continuous function, than you have to sum slopes of a tangent line at every instant (point) and divide by "number of slopes" (yeah, there are infinite number of these!). That is where integral comes in handy. Integral from [a,b] of $f'(t)$ means "sum all slopes from all tangent lines from interval [a,b]". Since you have 'infinite' "number of slopes" of a tangent lines, you can say that "number of slopes" = integral of 1 from a to b and therefore number of slopes = b-a.

Comment: If the two points are $(0,0)$ and $(5,1)$ the slope of the line through them is $\frac 15$, which fits my intuition of average slope.  It is the same as average speed of a vehicle-just take the total distance divided by the total time.

Comment: Part 1: but I still don't understand how that correlates with an idea of taking an average of some set. I understand what you are saying and I get it how they got from idea "sum of slopes/number of slopes=average" to the point $s(t2)-s(t1)/total time$ but why on intuitive level you can say "average slope = calculate slope between two endpoints".. for example: take an average of these numbers: $4,5,6,7,12$. you sum them all up and divide by 5 (there are five numbers you are averaging) and you get a result.

Comment: Part 2:  here, you take two endpoints subtract values of function at that two points and divide by the size of the interval and you obtain average slope. it is much more intuitive to me to say that average slope is sum of all slopes divided by the number of slopes you added and you obtain average slope by calculating that.

Comment: If you have the set $4,5,6,7,12$ and want to average the increases, you take $\frac 14((5-4)+(6-5)+(7-6)+(12-7))=\frac 14(12-4)=2$

Comment: Ahaaaaa, nice that cleared a lot of 'holes'! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider a partition of $[a,b]$ into subintervals $I_k:=[x_{k-1},x_k]$ $\ (1\leq k\leq N)$. You  would then define the *measured slope* of $f$ on the subinterval $I_k$ by
$$m_k:={f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})\over x_k-x_{k-1}}\qquad(1\leq k\leq N)\ .$$
Note that
$$f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})=m_k(x_k-x_{k-1})\qquad(1\leq k\leq N)
\ ,$$
and therefore
$$\sum_{k=1}^N m_k(x_k-x_{k-1})=\sum_{k=1}^N\bigl(f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})\bigr)=f(b)-f(a)$$
(a telescopic sum), or
$$\sum_{k=1}^N {x_k-x_{k-1}\over b-a}m_k={f(b)-f(a)\over b-a}\ .\tag{1}$$
This shows that the weighted mean of the measured slopes over the small subintervals $I_k$ is equal to the measured slope over the total interval $[a,b]$, **before any limit is taken**.

How does $f'$ come in here? By the MVT for each $k\in[N]$ there is a $\xi_k\in I_k$ such that $m_k=f'(\xi_k)$. The LHS of $(1)$ can therefore be rewritten as
$$\sum_{k=1}^N f'(\xi_k)\>{x_k-x_{k-1}\over b-a}\ ,$$
which is a Riemann sum for
$${1\over b-a}\int_a^b f'(t)\>dt\ .$$
Since $(1)$ is true also "in the limit" we arrive at your formula in a "natural way", i.e., without making use of the FTC.

Comment: Neat! Thank you so much, sir!

Comment: but there is still a "catch": "You  would then define the *average slope* of $f$ on the subinterval $I_k$ by
$$m_k:={f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})\over x_k-x_{k-1}}\qquad(1\leq k\leq N)\ .$$"
which is the part I don't understand intutevely at all. how can "average slope" at any interval be "difference between two endpoints divided by the interval size" (aka slope of a... antiderivative (primitive function $F(x)$ between two endpoints). PS: I understand it at the level: average of $4,5,6$ is $4+5+6/3$ and I understand that avg slope is sum of all slopes/number of slopes (left side of the equation).

Comment: I have edited my answer slightly in order to avoid the word "average". But note that on the LHS of $(1)$ we have an average of slopes.